# Elastic Bamboo CI Windows Server - MSBuild 12 not publishing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I have a custom image with Node.js, Microsoft Build Tools 2013, Windows SDK for Windows 8.1, .Net Framework 4.5.1 SDK, Microsoft Test Controller for Visual Studio 2013, Microsoft Agents for Visual Studio 2013 and Microsoft Web Deploy 3.5 installed.

Most things are working but I am struggling to get the project to package.  I do not need the project to deploy directly to a web server; a zip will do fine.

On my dev machine I have a publish profile set that creates a folder with the content of my web project as I would expect.  On the build server the project builds with no errors but no publishing happens.  No error messages either.

I have tried a lot of potential solutions and these range from VS2010 to VS2013 but I have not had a success yet.

My publish profile and configuration is DevTest:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" MyWeb.csproj /p:Configuration=DevTest /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0 /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:Configuration=DevTest

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to get this to work but I don't have a clean answer.  I am guessing this is why there has not been any replies.

MSBuild is a complex beast mostly because it references many paths outside of the project.  In my instance MSBuild was looking for ReportViewer.WebForms and other references in different installation locations.  My project was referencing v10 but the reference location MSBuild was using looking for version 11.